Как сайт может определить selenium, и как это обойти
Возникла проблема, что сайт обнаруживает selenium и дает капчу, которую невозможно пройти. Используется selenium на java, браузер - Chrome. Может попробовать firefox или использовать coockie? Вот опции, которые используются при создании драйвера:
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"); // Убираем флаг автоматизации
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--incognito");

String script = "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Array; " +
                "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_JSON;" +
                "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Object;" +
                "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Promise;" +
                "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Proxy;" +
                "delete window.cdc_adoQpoasnfa76pfcZLmcfl_Symbol;";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("source", script);
driver.executeCdpCommand("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", params);

Такой код обходит Cloudflare, но не hCaptcha

Конкретно у селениума есть тулзы патча драйвера для его анти детекта, пример анти-детекта, судя по описанию уже имеет обход клаудфлаера. Что касается капчи, то любой платный сервис предоставляет возможность решать капчу за небольшую плату, пример решения капчи.

Вам не удастся обойти детектирование selenium простой сменой браузера на firefox.
Лучшее, что можно сделать в этом случае - копаться в заголовках, сверяя и подделывая каждый http - заголовок. Причем, само по себе это не является панацеей: возможно, придётся эмулировать поведение пользователя на сайте, включая перемещение мышки, паузы, прокрутку страницы и т.п.
Возможно, лучшее решение - интегрировать в свой проект разгадывание капчи, например, при помощи одного из проектов типа такого (это не реклама, просто с ним я работал, и понимаю, что с его помощью задача - решаема)

Насчет капчи понял вас, спасибо. Не могли бы вы привести статью или другой любой источник насчет обхода детектирования selenium.
